# MySQL LOAD XML LOCAL slows down after first 100k entries

Tags: mysql, xml, shell

I am trying to import a large XML (arround 700MB) into a MySQL database. It is working so far but the thing is, it is terribly slow. The XML contains arround 300k entries. The first 100k entries are quite fast, from then on every +1000 entries need about 5min.

Schema of the corresponding MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
`PHAR` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`PRDNO` varchar(10),
`SMCAT` varchar(5),
`DSCRLONGD` varchar(200),
`DSCRLONGF` varchar(200),
`QTYUD` varchar(10),
`QTYUF` varchar(10),
`IMG2` varchar(50),
`DSCRPACKD` varchar(200),
`DSCRPACKF` varchar(200),
`NOPCS` int(11),
`WEIGHT` varchar(50)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The xml which I am trying to import:

```
<ARTICLE CREATION_DATETIME="2017-06-27T13:23:04.2814446+02:00" PROD_DATE="2017-06-27T00:00:00" VALID_DATE="2017-06-27T00:00:00" xmlns="http://www.hcisolutions.ch/index">
  <ART DT="2016-08-08T00:00:00+02:00">
    <PHAR>0020244</PHAR>
    <PHARMACODE>20244</PHARMACODE>
    <GTIN>7680316440115</GTIN>
    <ARTNO>20244</ARTNO>
    <GRPCD>M1</GRPCD>
    <CDSO1>03.00.00.00</CDSO1>
    <PRDNO>24538</PRDNO>
    <SMCAT>C</SMCAT>
    <SMNO>31644011</SMNO>
    <HOSPCD>N</HOSPCD>
    <CLINCD>N</CLINCD>
    <ARTTYP>0</ARTTYP>
    <VAT>2</VAT>
    <SALECD>N</SALECD>
    <INSLIM>N</INSLIM>
    <LIMPTS>0</LIMPTS>
    <GRDFR>0</GRDFR>
    <TEMP>15/25</TEMP>
    <BG>N</BG>
    <EXP>60</EXP>
    <QTY>30</QTY>
    <DSCRD>FERRO-GRADUMET Depottabl 30 Stk</DSCRD>
    <DSCRF>FERRO-GRADUMET cpr dépôt 30 pce</DSCRF>
    <DSCRLONGD>Ferro-Gradumet Depottabl 30 Stk</DSCRLONGD>
    <DSCRLONGF>Ferro-Gradumet cpr dépôt 30 pce</DSCRLONGF>
    <SORTD>FERRO-GRADUMET DEPOTTABL 30 STK</SORTD>
    <SORTF>FERRO-GRADUMET CPR DÉPÔT 30 PCE</SORTF>
    <QTYUD>Stk</QTYUD>
    <QTYUF>pce</QTYUF>
    <MULT>1</MULT>
    <NOPCS>30</NOPCS>
    <MINI>14</MINI>
    <DEPCD>N</DEPCD>
    <LOACD>N</LOACD>
    <STTOX>N</STTOX>
    <GGL>N</GGL>
    <SMDAT>1967-06-22T00:00:00+02:00</SMDAT>
    <BAGDOSSIER>10696</BAGDOSSIER>
    <DEL>false</DEL>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>1836</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>H</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>685230</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>685230</ARTNO2>
      <ARTNO3>685230</ARTNO3>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>1836</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>V</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>685230</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>685230</ARTNO2>
      <ARTNO3>685230</ARTNO3>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>5360</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>L</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>685230</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>685230</ARTNO2>
      <ARTNO3>685230</ARTNO3>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTBAR>
      <CDTYP>E13</CDTYP>
      <BC>7680316440115</BC>
      <BCSTAT>A</BCSTAT>
    </ARTBAR>
    <ARTCH>
      <PHAR2>4204981</PHAR2>
      <CHTYPE>SDO</CHTYPE>
      <LINENO>1</LINENO>
      <NOUNITS>30</NOUNITS>
    </ARTCH>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>1999-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PPUB</PTYP>
      <PRICE>10.9</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>2005-07-22T00:00:00+02:00</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PEXF</PTYP>
      <PRICE>7.92</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
    <ARTINS>
      <VDAT>2004-07-01T00:00:00+02:00</VDAT>
      <INCD>3</INCD>
      <NINCD>30</NINCD>
    </ARTINS>
  </ART>
  <ART>...</ART
  </ARTICLE>
```

I try to import it using a the follwing MySQL command:

LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '~/Desktop/HCI/Article.xml' INTO TABLE articles ROWS 
   IDENTIFIED BY '';

Is there anything I can do to speed it up? Other XMLs (same size, maybe less tags/attributes) are much faster (they need arround 5mins in total).

I would appreciate it to get some help from you.

My machine: Apple Macbook Pro i7, 3.1Ghz, 16GB Ram, 1TB SSD.

Thanks in advance guys and girls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the `ARTCOMP` etc (so the more indented part of the data) processed?  FK relations? Because I think you just ran out of memory and MySQL decided to use tmp, or the system started swapping.

Comment: Hi Norbert
Since they are not part of my SQL table scheme I suppose they are ignored? Could that be the issue? Is there I way to "exclude" them from LOAD?

Comment: They are ignored, but you might just hit an optimization issue in the XML parser in this scenario. Pre-parse the file to strip out the unwanted blocks is the quickest way to discover that (you are going to want to use regex :) )

Comment: Hi Norbert
I was able to strip out all "complex" child tags of the XML. It now only takes 80MB. But the import is still very strange. The first 100k rows are entered quite fast and from then on it slows extremly down. Any idea what the issue might be? For me it looks as if the amount of commits/rows affected is the limiting factor and not the complexity of the single item. What do you think?

Comment: LOAD DATA infile is usually the fastest way to load data. Your other hypothesis was that the width of the column might be an issue. Since you eliminated the other potential issue, you are probably right. You might have to write your own loader with commit points, or split the file in chunks and load those so that you stay under the threshold you are now running into.

Comment: Hi Norbert
Thanks for getting back to me. Is there a simple way how I can split the XML file into multiple files using a shell command?

Comment: You can use `split` which will split the file in x parts (split uses line count), then inspect every file for the correct delimiter with awk so you can move the (at this moment incorrect split) part to the correct file (append to previous file, cut from current file). Split is quite fast, so the whole action should run in a few minutes (with your original 700MB file since the other action did not really help)